# Word alignment for Switchboard Dialogue Acts Corpus

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, dialog-acts, syllable-timing

I am trying to connect the dialogue acts of the [Switchboard Dialogue Acts Corpus](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/ws97/) with the word alignment timing information available [here](https://www.isip.piconepress.com/projects/switchboard/).

I can see how it is possible to match up every utterance with every word. For example, this utterance is labeled with the conversation number:

```
| swda_filename            | ptb_basename | conversation_no | transcript_index | act_tag | caller | utterance_index | subutterance_index | text                                                                       |
|--------------------------|--------------|-----------------|------------------|---------|--------|-----------------|--------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| sw00utt/sw_0001_4325.utt | 4/sw4325     | 4325            | 3                | +       | A      | 3               | 1                  | What kind of experience [ do you, + do you ] have, then with child care? / |
```

And can be aligned word-by-word to the information available in individual ISIP files, e.g.:

```
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 4.495250 4.705000 what
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 4.705000 4.908250 kind
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 4.908250 5.008750 of
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 5.008750 5.669625 experience
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 5.669625 5.801375 [silence]
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 5.801375 5.889125 do
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 5.889125 6.122625 you
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 6.122625 6.321625 do
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 6.321625 6.471625 you
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 6.471625 6.801625 have
sw4325A-ms98-a-0005 6.801625 7.168375 then
```

I am sure this alignment would contain a lot of errors and one-off misalignments/exceptions. Is this sort of utterance-level information available with word-by-word annotation, so that I do not need to duplicate an existing effort?